# Linq query returning the same result over and over

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq query returning the same result over and over even though the "cptAuxList" variable is changing:

```
    static Func<VBANKDataContext, decimal, IQueryable<SldValue>> GetSldAll = CompiledQuery.Compile((VBANKDataContext VB, decimal date) =>
        (from cpt in VB.AGSFCA
         where cptAuxList.Contains(cpt.CPTAUX)
         && cpt.FINPRD == date
         select new SldValue() {
            AUX = cpt.CPTAUX,
            SNS = cpt.SNSSLD,
            SLD = cpt.SLDCPT
         })
    );
```

The list is being resetted every 2000 unique values stored:

```
    static void AddIfNotContains(string CPTAUX)
    {
        string cptAuxToAdd = CPTAUX.Trim();

        if (!cptAuxList.Contains(cptAuxToAdd) && !cptAuxDone.Contains(cptAuxToAdd))
        {
            cptAuxList.Add(cptAuxToAdd);

            if (cptAuxList.Count >= 2000)
            {
                VBANKDataContext VB = new VBANKDataContext();
                List<SoldeValue> auxToSldTemp = GetSoldeAll(VB, DateDernArt).ToList();
                auxToSld.AddRange(auxToSldTemp);

                cptAuxDone.AddRange(cptAuxList);
                cptAuxList.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

The variable is declared this way:

```
 static List<string> cptAuxList = new List<string>();
```

What seems to happen is that the first time I call "GetSldAll", it works as expected, and then the next calls, it returns the same result as the first one like if the values contained in the cptAuxList list doesn't change.

Comment: What about debugging your code and set a breakpoint at the `if` condition for the +2000 entries and then step line for line in your code ahead and see what values will be put into your `cptAuxList` later on. Maybe you start putting the same values from the beggining again into your list.

Comment: I've done it earlier and the values actually change. I've tried to add a breakpoint when I call the Add method for cptAuxList too for a specific value I stored in the first 2000 stored values and it looks like it doesn't stop so I don't think a value that has been previously stored in cptAuxList is stored in again.

Comment: Try putting the context in a `using` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only *variable* you defined is the date. Everything else is taken in the moment it is compiled. That's the whole point of *compiling* it: reuse.

If you need `cptAuxList` to be a variable as well, you need to define it as one.